# Help with wiring in an Indicator light

Tags: voltage, wiring, series

I am working on a box for a project and I get a significant voltage drop when I wire in an indicator light.

This is an AC project and the light is a "Lamp 240v, Watts 0.5 Model 1609W21E BA".

It is wired in series, with it going from the wall to a switch, from the switch to the indicator light, and then to a black box.

wall -> switch -> indicator -> black box.

When measuring the voltage coming into the indicator light I get 110v, when I measure the voltage going out I get 40v, a 70v drop.

Am I using the wrong kind of light? Or do I need to wire it in parallel (I was told it should be in series though).

Any help on determining why I get such a drop would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 0.5W 240V light will have a circuit resistance of about 115kohms. Given the circuit you have described, what you measure doesn't suprise me. What's the resistance of the black box? Is it about 65kohm?

It's impossible to say if you are using the wrong sort of light - what were expectations for the as-yet-undisclosed black box. Wiring in parallel may be an option but I can't tell what you wanted from what you've told us.

Comment: Sorry forgot to come back, it was a long night, we had to rewire it into parallel.